# wstring to LPCWSTR not working with c_str()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, directx, directx-11

I am currently doing DirectX11 and trying to convert a UTF8 string into a LPCWSTR. I've written a utility function to aid me in the conversion:

```
// Convert an UTF8 string to a wide Unicode String
std::wstring WidenString(const std::string &string)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string.c_str(), string.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstring(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string.c_str(), string.size(), &wstring[0], size_needed);
    return wstring;
}
```

I've used the debugger to verify if it works. This is working:

Debugger says wndClassEx.lpszClassName = L"Hello"

```
std::wstring str = WidenString("Hello");
wndClassEx.lpszClassName = str.c_str();
```

This is not working:

Debugger says wndClassEx.lpszClassName = L"ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮ..."

```
wndClassEx.lpszClassName = WidenString("Hello").c_str();
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WidenString()` returns a `wstring` by value. In the first snippet, `wndClassEx.lpszClassName` will point to a valid memory location as long as the variable `str` remains in scope i.e. it does not get destroyed.

In the second case the return value does go out of scope at the end of the expression (at the `;`) and `wndClassEx.lpszClassName` then points to invalid memory.

Comment: @TerenceLam It's difficult to say how exactly to solve the problem without more context of where the code is being used. If you're passing the `WNDCLASSEX` structure to something like `RegisterClassEx` immediately, then the first version you've posted is the way to solve it. In the general case, the lifetime of the return value from `WidenString` must be at least as long as that of the `WNDCLASSEX` struct instance.